# ProxMox Ubuntu 20.04 Server VM Stopped working - Fails to boot Libmount.so.1 - Invalid ELF

Tags: ubuntu, proxmox

So I've had this VM running ProxMox for the last 18 months no issues.

I build a new ProxMox Server, and migrated this VM to the new server.

Now when it boots, I get the following screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIasL.png

I have ran Tux Rescue and others and checked disks through, and nothing obvious show or to repair.

Sadly I have data on here including a mysql database with no backup (Yes I know I am a noob for not backing it up)

Any thoughts on getting this to boot would be amazing.

Regards

PG

Comment: Does the new server have a different hardware, maybe even a different archictecture?

Comment: are you sure to run proxmox on ubuntu? Because it uses Debian and not ubuntu?! @gerald he uses ubuntu, not debian the system is broken IMHO - And for the mysql issue: run any recuse media and copy the whole mysql data folder and install it with the same config and datafolder it will do the job

Comment: @GeraldSchneider nope, when you migrate the VM in ProxMox it creates the new VM, and creates the hardware profile, and copies the disks, so all identical.  Moved other VM's with no issues.  All my other VM's are also Ubuntu 20.04 server

Comment: @djdomi, the server isnt running Ubuntu 20.04 with ProxMox.  Its  a ProxMox server, with a VM that is Ubuntu Server 20.04

Answer (score 1):

Likely a filesystem corruption.  You should try:

- running `fsck`.
- booting with `init=/bin/bash` (or manipulating VM files from the host) and inspecting ELF headers of `libmount.so.1` and nearby `so` libraries. Copying this file from [the original deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libmount1) file may fix this problem.
- If corruption is wide-spread, you may need to run `debsums`: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/debsums.1.html

After the problem is fixed, please look at your SMART stats.  You can also look at using software raid.

Comment: Had already run a fsck, with no issues found.  Will try the booting option later today